# Sort a list of random arrays from largest to smallest

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Alright for my assignment, I have to sort series of random numbers in order from largest to smallest.
The random numbers are going from indexOfMaxInRange, take the index of the largest number return that. In swapElements,it basically have to swap the index with the highest element to a[0], second highest to a[1] and so on. These two methods are passed through sortarray.
Please give me some input on how to finish this and what I am doing wrong thank you. 
PS: Not everything are called in the code, for various reason such as printing.

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] array = randomIntArray (10);   
    int index = indexOfMaxInRange (array, -5, 15 );
    swapElement (array, index, 0);

}

  public static int randomInt (int low, int high){ // Create a serie of random numbers
    int x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        x = (int)(Math.random ()* (high - low) +low);

    }  
    return x;

}
public static int[] randomIntArray (int n) { // Size of array
    int[] a = new int [n];
    for (int i = 0; i <a.length; i++){
        a[i] = randomInt (-5, 15);
    }
    return a;
}

public static int indexOfMaxInRange (int[] a, int low , int high){ //Find the index of the largest element
    int [] b = new int [a.length];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length-1; i++){
        if (a[i] >= low && a[i] < high)index++;  
        if (a[i] > a[i+1]){ 
            b[i] = a[i]; 


        }
        System.out.println (b[i]+"\t"+ (index));
    }  
    return index ;

}
public static int swapElement (int []a, int index , int i){ // Swap the element within the array
    int temp = 0;
    System.out.println ();
    for ( i = 0; i <a.length; i++){
        temp = index;
        a[i] = a[a.length - i - 1]; 
        temp = a[a.length - i - 1]; 


        System.out.println (temp + "\t"+ index);
   } 
    return temp;
}

public static void sortArray (int[] array){ 

    for (int i = 0; i <array.length; i++){    
    int index = indexOfMaxInRange (array, -5, 15 );
    swapElement (array, index, 0);

        System.out.println (); // This will print out the newly arranged order of the numbers.
    }
}
```

Comment: you probably want to say what/where things go wrong.

Comment: otherwise you're only swapping once, you're going to need to do that a few more times if you actually want to sort your list.

Comment: I am not getting what you are saying, do what Jay?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SortArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] unsortedArray = getRandomArray(10, -5, 15);
        printArray("Unsorted Array:", unsortedArray);
        System.out.println("Max element is at index: "+getMaxElementIndex(unsortedArray));
        printArray("Sorted Array in descending order:", sortArray("desc", unsortedArray));
        printArray("Sorted Array in asending order:", sortArray("asc", unsortedArray));
    }

    public static int[] getRandomArray(int length, int min, int max) {
        if(length == 0)
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot create a zero length array.");
        int[] toReturn = new int[length];

        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            toReturn[i] = getRandomNumber(min, max, toReturn);
        }
        return toReturn;
    }

    public static int getRandomNumber(int min, int max, int[] array) {  
        int toReturn = (int)(Math.random ()* (max - min) +min);
        for(int i = 0; i<array.length;i++)
        {
            //Avoid duplicates and recurse if the number is already found in the array.
            if(toReturn == array[i])
                toReturn = getRandomNumber(min, max, array);
        }
        return toReturn;
    }

    public static void printArray(String label, int[] array) {
        System.out.println(label);
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
            System.out.print(array[i]+" ");
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static int getMaxElementIndex(int[] array) {
        int maxNum = -9999999;
        int index = -9999999;
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
        {
            if(maxNum == -9999999 || array[i] >= maxNum) {
                maxNum = array[i];
                index = i;
            }

            if(index == -9999999 && i == array.length - 1)
                index = i;
        }
        return index;
    }

    public static int[] sortArray(String direction, int[] array) {
        int temp = 0;
        if(direction.equalsIgnoreCase("desc") || direction.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            for(int i=0; i<array.length - 1; i++) {
                for(int j = i; j < array.length; j++) {
                    if(array[j] >= array[i]) {
                        temp = array[j];
                        array[j] = array[i];
                        array[i] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else if(direction.equalsIgnoreCase("asc")) {
            for(int i=0; i<array.length - 1; i++) {
                for(int j = i; j < array.length; j++) {
                    if(array[j] <= array[i]) {
                        temp = array[j];
                        array[j] = array[i];
                        array[i] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return array;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you but um.. I think that is a little too advanced for me sry. Could you please just help me with my indexofmaxinrange and swap methods? That would be great. Thank you.